# HOW to rewrite links like this?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a link, let's say: http://site.com/profile.php?id=1 ....In a normal mode, with a normal rewrite I'd have something like: http://site.com/profile/1 . But,...What I want is.....how can I get from the database the username that belongs to the user with the id 1 and make the url http://site.com/profile/FinalDestiny ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you meaning to generate the URLs or to process the URLs? If generate, then what framework are you using (if any)? If process then you can do it the same way as you would with an ID, but search based on the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteMap) function of `mod_rewrite`, but you have to store your id-username pairs either into a text file or a DBM file-based database. Keep in mind that to use this directive you have first to declare it inside **httpd.conf**, so access and write permissions to httpd.conf are required.

If your users are stored in another database (MySQL or such) I'd suggest you use a text file and simply overwrite it any time an user is added or deleted.

If you've got enough users to make using a DBM a sensible choice you can either try to use PHP's [DBA functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.dba.php) or make a text file as above and use Apache's utility [httxt2dbm](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/programs/httxt2dbm.html) to convert it into a database (via `exec()` or such).

`RewriteMap` also allows using an external program (say, a PHP CLI script) to return the URL mapping, but it seems like overkill...

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a rule which rewrites `http://site.com/profile/FinalDestiny` to `http://site.com/profile.php?username=FinalDestiny` and then do a database query in `profile.php` to find the id of the user with that username.

Comment: Nono, I want to use ID ...http://site.com/profile.php?id=1. with profile.php?username=FinalDestiny I know how to do it too..but I want with id.